# How to change business unit in Dynamics CRM 365 while adding users manually?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I have business units for different countries like Germany, France, UK, Netherlands
the default one is global. Now by while adding users I need to check email-id and change the business unit to particular country. Could anyone help on this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have on-premise environment to test, but I remember in old version CRM on-premise instances there used to be an option to create single/multiple user. The user creation dialog will allow you to choose BU, Security role to start with and then add users from AD. But you cannot have multiple variations of BU, roles in single setup step. You have to do it multiple times then.

Anyway you can choose to change the BU of any user by following this step: (Bulk change also possible by choosing multiple users at one time)

[image]

**Edit**:

You can write a post-create plugin on system user entity to check the email & update the Business unit using `SetBusinessSystemUserRequest` message.

```
    SetBusinessSystemUserRequest changeUserBURequest = new SetBusinessSystemUserRequest();  
     changeUserBURequest.BusinessId = BusinessUnitGUID;
     changeUserBURequest.UserId = UserGUID;
     changeUserBURequest.ReassignPrincipal = new EntityReference(“systemuser”, UserGUID);
     crmService.Execute(changeUserBURequest);
```

[Reference](https://crmtipsbyprm.wordpress.com/2015/04/13/change-user-business-unit-with-dynamics-crm-sdk/)

Comment: Thank for your comments.Any possiblity to do in automated way of change business unit  instead of manually changing